# Joining files with cat

Tags: bash, join, cat

i'm doing a script to download one file in multiple parts, i'm in the part of joining that files. I can join the parts outside of the script with

```
cat name.part{0..4} > name.ext
```

But, if i use this in the script

```
cat $filename.part{0..$N} > $filename
```

i get:

```
cat: Bitcoin-960x623.jpg.part{0..5}: No such file or
```

Comment: This is a faq of sorts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{0..4}` is a brace expansion; `$N` is a variable expansion.  Your expression doesn't work as you expect because brace expansion happens before variable expansion:

*The order of expansions is: brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter, variable, and arithmetic expansion and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion), word splitting, and filename expansion.*

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions

You can use the [`seq` command](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/seq-invocation.html) instead of a brace expansion to generate the required filenames up to arbitrary N:

```
$ filename=myfile
$ N=4
$ cat $(seq -f "$filename.part%g" 0 $N) > name.ext
$
```

---

In the unlikely event `seq -f` is unavailable, you can use a for loop one-liner instead:

```
$ cat $(for ((i=0; i<N; i++)); do echo "$filename.part$i"; done) > name.ext
$
```

Comment: OTOH seq is nonstandard, nonportable, and may not support `printf`-style format strings. You may have to use `printf "$filename.part%g" $(jot $N 0 $((N+1)) )`, for example. Or just use `extglob`.

Comment: This my be true about `seq`, although I found it installed (with `-f`) on all Linux distros I could lay my hands one (including a couple of embedded), as well as OSX.  Conversely, the only place I found `jot` installed by default is OSX.  Even Ubuntu 12.04 needed it installing.  Also, `jot $((N+1)) 0 $N` works better here than `jot $N 0 $((N+1))`

Answer (score 3):

I solved with this.

```
for (( k=0 ; k<=$N ; k++ ))
do
cat $filename.part$k >> $filename
done
```

Comment: This isn't bad, but if you move the `>> $filename` outside the loop it would be one `open` syscall instead of many `open for append` syscalls. (Also, don't forget to quote $filename.)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use variables inside curly braces in shell. `eval` can be used here:

```
eval "$filename.part{0..$N} > $filename"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Assertion**: I'm going to argue that this answer is *better*. (Something I don't do often or lightly.) My rationale is that all of the other answers here at the time of this edit just expand to a range of integers, whether the files matching those integers exist or not. By using glob expansions you guarantee you will not encounter `No such file or directory` from `cat`. In all other cases with brace expansion, eval, `seq` and a for loop you'd have to explicitly check.

If there are fewer than 10 total filenames:

```
cat "$filename".part[0-9]
```

will expand as a glob to however many names there are. This is a fast and portable solution, but obviously limited. If there are more than 10 then that pattern will only match the ones with one digit, so you have to get a bit wilier and use [extglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob):

```
shopt -s extglob
cat "$filename".part+([0-9])
```

should do it, but this will only work for the Bourne-Again SHell. (That said, several other modern shells have expansion capabilities similar to extglob.)

Comment: To play the devil's advocate, the `No such file or directory` errors from `cat` may be very useful.  If one of the required input files was missing, this would be silently ignored by the wildcard version, but may have unintended side-effects.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I'm usually on the side of *Errors should never pass silently. Unless explicitly silenced.*, but in this case it would be more effective to check for missing files before executing `cat` at all, lest your unintended side-effects happen *anyway*.